# Need similar jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I want to have jQuery slide show plugin similar to this http://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/ramada-encore-inverness.en-gb.html

Can any one suggest me, which plugin they are using?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using a custom plugin. Please see a list of plugins that do the same [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/).

Comment: Actually I want to have all the images appear at once. Currently I am using jquery plugin named "Fotarma" http://fotorama.io/. Here you can take a look. http://www.maldivesresortdeals.com/Hotel/Adaaran_Club_Rannalhi.html.....Please suggest what changes I need to make to appear all images at once.

Comment: What do you mean with 'all at once'? Do you mean that the 'overview' is scrolling and not continuing on a new line?

Comment: I do think however, that what you have now, might even be more user-friendly than the one from booking.com. I would however recommend you use some scrollbars instead of dragging it.

Comment: But, if that is really what you want, please refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74hur/

Comment: If you can look at the current one and click on the last thubmnail which is in the navigation, the rest of the images appear but I want to have all the thumbnail display at the same time. I don't want the scrolling in the navigation. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at that fiddle I posted ;) http://jsfiddle.net/74hur/